# Sending data to a server for computation

Tags: iphone, http, networking, send

I want to create an application which will will be a webapp. I want to collect the data from the user, send it to a server where the computation will take place, and have the result displayed on the iPhone screen. The server normally takes results from a regular webpage via text fields and computes it and displays the result on the webpage. I just want the send the data via iPhone. Navigating my iPhone safari to the webpage is NOT an option, as the webpage is not optimized. So I how do I send data to the server, make it compute the results and have the results displayed on my iPhone?

Thank you.

Regards

EDIT:
I have no control over the server. Imagine my case to be as follows: The user enters a word, the word is sent by the iPhone to a Google server, the server compiles the search results and sends it back to my iPhone, and then the iPhone displays this result on the screen.Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using ASIHTTPRequest/ASIFormDataRequest if you want to submit form data to your existing web page using form fields (per your description.)

In general I find ASIHTTPRequest friendlier to use than NSURLConnection / NSURLRequest.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I will see into this technology....in the mean time do you have an easier solution to implement? I am a novice when it comes to server communication!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use `NSMutableURLRequest` to create the GET or POST request, and then `NSURLConnection` to (asynchronously) send the data and receive the result. You could also use any number of third-party libraries to do the same thing.

As for the server side of things, you would have it accept a GET or POST just as you would with a web-based app, and output data in an appropriate format.

As for the output format that will be parsed by your app: With the standard classes, you can easily parse plist data and (with a little more work) XML; third-party libraries can be found to parse json and many other formats, if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I have no control over the server. Imagine my case to be as follows: The user enters a word, the word is sent by the iPhone to a Google server, the server compiles the search results and sends it back to my iPhone, and then the iPhone displays this result on the screen.Any more suggestions?

Comment: I think Anomie has the right idea here. Basically you are making a small web browser here. In the Google example, you would do a GET request to get the search results, parse the response HTML and then create controls on the screen to visualize it.